# LaTeX doesn't recognize \end{array}

Tags: matrices, arrays

Following code

```
... \begin{align}
\begin{array}
1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{array}
\end{align}...
```

results in numerous errors:

```
 - Argument of \array has an extra }   (line 0)
 - Missing $ inserted \end{align}
 - Missing \endgroup inserted \end{align} 
 - Extra }, or forgotten $ \end{align} 
 - \begin{align} on input line 101 ended by \end{array}. \end{align} 
 - Misplaced alignment tab character & \end{align}   (2x, same line) 
 - Misplaced \omit \end{align} 
 - Misplaced \cr \end{align}
 - Misplaced alignment tab character & \end{align} (2x)
 - Misplaced \cr \end{align} 
 - Extra }, or forgotten $ \end{align} (2x)
 - Missing number, treated as zero \end{align}
 - Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) \end{align}
 - Missing number, treated as zero (3x, line 0)
 - Missing $ inserted \end{align} 
 - Display math should end with $$ (line 0)
 - Missing $ inserted \end{align}
 - Missing \endgroup inserted \end{align}
 - Extra }, or forgotten $ \end{align} 
 - Missing $ inserted \end{align} 
 - Too many }'s \end{align} 
 - \begin{document} ended by \end{array}. (line 0) 
 - Misplaced \noalign \end{align} (2x)
 -  Too many }'s \end{align}
 - \begin{document} ended by \end{align}. \end{align} 
 - Display math should end with $$ (line 0)
```

Of course code without this compiles just fine.

All errors are at line 109 (`\end{align}`), except those at line 0.

Matrix environment ([examples](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=146358)) also compiles with errors, but fewer. These are:

```
 - Paragraph ended before \array was complete I've inserted a
   begin-math/end-math symbol since I think

 - Missing \right. inserted I've inserted something that you may have
   forgotten.

 - Missing \endgroup inserted
```

I'm using TexStudio on Ubuntu. I also tried with Geany but it throws the same errors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. Glad somebody answered your question. In general it is better if you provide a complete minimal working example that people con compile (so including `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}` and so on). Happy TeXing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify the `array` format; for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{array}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some new information has been given in the comments; the problem comes from using the `arrayjob` and `amsmath` packages simultaneously, as this example shows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arrayjob}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{array}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Processing the above document triggers the error

```
! Argument of \array has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.12 \end{align}
```

The conflict comes from the macro name `\array` used by `arrayjob` which conflicts with macros in `amsmath`; the `arrayjobx` package (which is an improved version of arrayjob) solves this issue using the macro `\arrayx` instead. Thus, in order to prevent the conflict between the packages `arrayjob` and `amsmath`, use `arrayjobx` instead of `arrayjob`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{array}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I am aware that there's no point in using `array` inside `align` as I did in my answer; if the only intent is to get a displayed (numbered) expression, the `equation` environment would be a better choice; if no display number is needed, then `\[...\]` is enough. I kept the original `align` just in the hope that the OP's actual expression deserves its use.

Comment: Sorry, forget to copy that. It works in new file, but not in mine. Maybe some package conflict?

Comment: @onetoomany then please reduce your file (by commenting out chunks, for example) until you get a minimal version allowing us to reproduce the problem and edit your question with this minimal version.

Comment: Again, I made an idiot out of myself. It was a conflict with an arrayjob package.

Comment: But now the question is, how to use two conflicting packages?

Comment: @onetoomany again, edit your question and add a complete minimal document illustrating the problem.

Comment: +1 although I wonder if it is appropriate to wrap an `array` in an `align` environment... It seems like it, unless there is more to the actual example, that one should just use `\[...\]` or else the `equation` environment

Comment: @cmhughes Yes, I agree with you. I kept the `align` environment only because I hope the actual expression used by the OP deserves its use.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I had to install TexLive 2012 first but had some problems. And there are olympics, other stuff, ... All solved now. Thanks!